# node-webkit won't run project file

Tags: node-webkit

I started experimenting with nwjs ( node-webkit ) .
But i seem to be doing something wrong i have 2 file in a folder :
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Node Webkit</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello Node Webkit</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp.helloworldapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A test app",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

i zip up both files at ones ( i don't zip the folder ) and i rename the extention from .zip to .nw but nothing happens when i try to open it with the nwjs app .

i'm working from a mac if that could have something to do with it ?

Comment: It work with older version of node-webkit, but doesn't work with new node-webkit including nwjs 0.12

Comment: For me it works with node 0.9.1 but not works with 0.11

Comment: Confirmed 0.9.1 does show my .nw file .

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the steps outlined in their [docs](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps).

From the command line:

- Go to your project directory a la cd ~/Projects/my_app
- Run zip -r ../${PWD##*/}.nw *
- Your fully-prepared .nw file shall be located
  right outside of your project directory
- Cake!